# combine two loops in python

Tags: python, optimization, coding-style

suppose to have two polygons p1 and p2, where p2 is completely inside p1

```
p1 = [(0, 10), (10, 10), (10, 0), (0, 0)]
p2 = [(2, 6), (6, 6), (6, 2), (2, 2)]

degree_of_contact = 0

xyarrays = [p1,p2]
p1_degree_of_contact = 0
for x,y in xyarrays[0]:
        if point_inside_polygon(x,y,xyarrays[1]):
            p1_degree_of_contact += 1

p2_degree_of_contact = 0
for x,y in xyarrays[1]:
        if point_inside_polygon(x,y,xyarrays[0]):
            p2_degree_of_contact += 1

degree_of_contact = p1_degree_of_contact + p2_degree_of_contact
```

where [point_inside_polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179405/python-debug-a-point-inside-polygon-function) is to deciding if a point is inside (True, False otherwise) a polygon,
where poly is a list of pairs (x,y) containing the coordinates of the polygon's vertices. The algorithm is called the "Ray Casting Method

i wish to combine in an elegant way (line coding save) both loops in one.

Comment: Since I think your work is relevant, take a look at numpy which has built in support for vectors and matrices. There are nice tricks you can do there (like vectorized loops) that are purely written in C and are very fast. And its not only for speed: there are tons of built-in math methods which should make your life easier for such problems.       http://www.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
degree_of_contact = 0
for tmp1, tmp2 in [(p1, p2), (p2, p1)]:
    for x,y in tmp1:
        if point_inside_polygon(x, y, tmp2):
            degree_of_contact += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
degree_of_contact = sum(point_inside_polygon(x, y, i) for i, j in ((p1, p2), (p2, p1)) for x, y in j)
```

Comment: I wonder if I can use this approach for my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68482842/python-double-for-loop-in-one-line/68482896#68482896