# Python: double for loop in one line

Tags: python, for-loop

I have such a loop:

```
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(A[i])):
            A[i][j] = functionA(A[i][j])
```

Is this possible to write more compact in Python?

Comment: Read [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) in python

Comment: Your code is perfectly readable as it is, trying to put everything in one line will not improve that.

Comment: You can use `zip` and `list comprehensions`

Comment: Making a list comprehension would actually make things worse for you if you do not have the understanding of what its doing

Comment: @PCM, the `zip()` function is not appropriate here, list comprehensions would not simplify anything.

Comment: In general (but not always) iterating over a list index is an anti-pattern in python. You should iterate over the actual elements as in  `for row in A:`. You can then iterate over the values in the row as `for element in row:` and now `element` is the same as your `a[i][j]`.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. Do you think you could write the code? Im having a hard time understanding. Otherwise, if you could give me a link to learn myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension.

Example code:

```py
A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
def functionA(a):
    return a+1

A = [[functionA(A[i][j]) for j in range(len(A[i]))] for i in range(len(A))]
print(A)
```

Result:

```
[[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10]]
```